# How to find the total of a column when the value is repeated multiple times? Trying to find the "final score" of a NHL game conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the final score of NHL hockey as a function of the away team and home teams goal count at the end of the game.

The values are repeated and at the end of each game I want to be able to easily determine which team won and create a new column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Game_Id':[200001,200001,200001],
         'Away_Score': [2,2,3],
         'Home_Score':[1,1,1],
          'Time_Elapsed' : ['19:21','19:29','19:29'],
         'Away_Team': ['MTL','MTL','MTL'],
         'Home_Team': ['BOS','BOS','BOS']})
```

---

Note: Final score of this game is 3 to 1 in favor of MTL (**not** 6 to 3 MTL)

I am trying to loop over numerous game and want to find the winner of the game by creating a column which considers the Away_Team and Home_Team score at the end of the game. I have many games I would like to do this with and I'm not sure how to do it.

Lastly, it may complicate things...and would be icing on the cake...but if you have any considerations as to how I could find the total score when the time_elapsed reached 0 that would be awesome too.

Something like `df[['Final_Score]]=?` but with a "loop"?

Comment: Stop rolling back edits, you are making your question unreadable.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed); plus, I kindly suggest you accept the edits from more experienced users that are trying to make your post more readable.

Comment: What do you mean "time_elapsed 0". Right now it's `19:29`.

Comment: Your input DataFrame has invalid syntax, you haven't provided a desired output.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve] with an actual valid DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

To get the last row for each game:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Game_Id':[200001, 200001, 200001],
         'Away_Score': [2,2,3],
         'Home_Score':[1,1,1],
          'Time_Elapsed' : ['19:21','19:29','19:29'],
         'Away_Team': ['MTL','MTL','MTL'],
         'Home_Team': ['BOS','BOS','BOS']})

df['Time_Elapsed'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time_Elapsed'] + ':00')
idx = df.groupby('Game_Id')['Time_Elapsed'].idxmax()
df.loc[idx]
```

Result:

```
   Game_Id  Away_Score  Home_Score Time_Elapsed Away_Team Home_Team
1   200001           2           1     19:29:00       MTL       BOS
```

Comment: hey one last question...how could I make it so this row is only created when the value of Time_Elapsed becomes 20:00? The code provided in the sample doesn't show the end of the game, but how could I create exactly what you have done above but only when the Time_Elapsed becomes 20:00?(aka at the end of the game)?

Comment: Doesn't `Time_Elapsed = 0` mean the start of a game?

Comment: the final score of the game should be 3 to 1. The time_elapsed uses Canadian hockey as a standard so the game actually counts "up" in Canada and the NHL uses this convention. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then change `idxmax()` to `idxmin()`

Comment: hey you totally answered this I'm so sorry I just connected the dots. Really cant thank you enough code different!